# Engine Type Confusion

Tags: engine, ford, o2-sensor, f-150

Can someone tell me the difference between these two engines? I'm trying to find an O2 sensor for my 2009 F150 and while looking for parts I came across this (apparently) very important distinction (note the "W" vs. the "8" at the end). I've looked on VIN # decoders but they stopped short of this information.

Thank you very much for your time.

BTW I'm not a mechanic so feel free to elaborate if you can.

- 4.6L v8 sohc distributorless naturally aspirated SFI electronic fi MFI 8

vs

- 4.6L v8 sohc distributorless naturally aspirated SFI electronic fi MFI W

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which O2 sensors are you looking for? The upstream (pre-cats), downstream (post-cats), or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To differentiate, you're looking for the **8th digit in the VIN**. Here's how it aligns:

- "W" is a 4.6L 2v
- "8" is a 4.6L 3v

The "2v" or "3v" denotes the quantity of valves per cylinder. It should more than likely say on the top of your engine whether it's a 2v or 3v engine (on the plastic bits).

As for the O2s themselves, it appears there are separate O2 sensors for left/right pre-cat and left/right post-cat, meaning, you could be looking at four different part numbers to replace all four of your sensors.

Comment: As a quick visual, 2v engine valve covers have a straight edge on both sides of the cover. The 3v valve cover has a straight edge on one side and a scalloped edge on the other.